# .htaccess to hide index.php with relative link issue

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to work with CodeIgniter these days.

By default it has the index.php in URI like this

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/home
```

`home` is a function inside a controller

But I don't want the `index.php` so I created the .htaccess file:

```
Allow from all
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|robots\.txt|script|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Basically it adds "index.php" automatically except when the conds are matched.

However here's the thing:
For URI like this: `http://www.example.com/home`
Everything works fine.

For URI like this: `http://www.example.com/home/`
Then the relative links in my webpage goes wild.
For example:
`css/common.css` was redirected to `index.php/home/css/common.css` resulting in the css file was not found.

Logs are like this:

```
strip per-dir prefix: [dir to my site]/home/css/common.css -> home/css/common.css
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'home/css/common.css'
rewrite 'home/css/common.css' -> 'index.php/home/css/common.css'
add per-dir prefix: index.php/home/css/common.css -> [dir to my site]/index.php/home/css/common.css
trying to replace prefix [dir to my site]/ with /
internal redirect with /index.php/home/css/common.css [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
add path info postfix: [dir to my site]/index.php -> [dir to my site]/index.php/home/css/common.css
strip per-dir prefix: [dir to my site]/index.php/home/css/common.css -> index.php/home/css/common.css
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/home/css/common.css'
pass through [dir to my site]/index.php
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not your rewrite rules - they are fine. What's happening is that the browser thinks `/home/` with a slash at the end is a real directory, so it prefixes all relative links to the directory it thinks it's in. The browser then dashes off a request for the CSS file, with path `/home/css/common.css`, which, naturally, gets rewritten since it doesn't match your check.

The quickest solution I see here is to use absolute paths for CSS files. Just link them as `/css/common.css` instead of the relative links you have now.

Comment: Actually I use a lot of links like that in my site. As long as all links are generated from my pages, they are fine. So can I just disregard this problem?

Comment: I don't know if you can disregard it - if it can't find the CSS file, isn't the rendering affected?

Comment: yes but as long as the links are generated by my pages they won't contain the last slash and seem working fine

Comment: Oh yeah in that case you should mostly be OK. But that is a brittle solution :) What if on some page you forget, or if someone else links to your pages and adds a slash?